# Keep referer upon Nginx redirect from one domain to another

Tags: nginx

Currently, my nginx site config looks like this:

```
server_name domain.me

location / {
   rewrite ^/ http://blog.domain.me
}
```

`domain.me` is fully under my control, while `blog.domain.me` is run by Github Pages.

My goal is to keep referer paths of visitor, who came to my blog via old link. Is there any way to keep Referer headers upon redirecting from one domain to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot affect the referral sending behavior of browsers with your nginx configuration.

It is the user's browser that sends the HTTP header for referral. HTTP specifications do not tell what should happen with 301 redirects and referral headers. So, browsers might send the referral data or they might not.

Comment: That's not true at all is it. Surely the Referrer Policy of the location that does the redirect will impact this.

Comment: You are correct, `Referrer-Policy` should affect browser behavior. However, since it is the browser that makes the decisions, it might still do something else than policy dictates.